# Would my "(object) identification" question be on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I know that there is a "story identification" tag, and is clear to know if the question is on-topic (by the description of the story containing Sci-Fi/fantasy elements).

There is also a "object-identification" but my problem is that, since I don't know what my object is, I can't use it in the proper way, like identifying an object within a franchise. I want to identify an object that clearly belongs to Sci-fi genre, without knowing the franchise.

My question would be like posting a picture of and X-wing and asking what kind of spaceship it is, without knowing that it is a Star Wars vehicle.

Comment: If it's clear that the thing you're identifying is related to a work of sci-fi or fantasy I think you'll be ok. Make sure you have done some of your own research -- and can show it -- or you risk getting downvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So long as you have valid reason to believe it is associated with a SF/F property, yes.

I had [my own object identification question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/106050/5184) which was well received and had no close votes.

Comment: useful. I also din't know there was a "toys" tag, which is quite relevant. Thanks.

Comment: Good answer. Another [example](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85416/21267) of 'object-identification'.